# Colocar imagen en notificaciones por email

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

estoy aprendiendo a usar las notificaciones de laravel por email.
mi pregunta es como puedo colocarle una imagen al correo ?

```
 public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $subject = sprintf('Gracias por solicitar tu Entrada!', config('app.name'), $this->fromUser->name);
    $greeting = sprintf('Hola %s!', $notifiable->name);

    return (new MailMessage)
                ->line("<img src='/logo.png' />")
                ->subject($subject)
                ->greeting($greeting)
                ->salutation('Atentamente, La Empresa')
                ->line('Su invitación fue procesada con éxito')
                ->line('Ahora puedes ver tu Entrada digital disponible en tu cuenta.')
                ->action('Ver mis entradas', url('/mis-reservas'));
}
```

en la primera linea adjunto un logo pero llega como texto a la bandeja.

Comment: Has intentado con poner la dirección completa de la imagen?, ejemplo: `https://nombre.com/carpeta/logo.png`

Comment: Desconozco `Laravel`, pero tengo entendido que no puedes enviar imágenes "locales" por correo electrónico. En su lugar, debes usar una url que apunte a un sitio web o a un banco de imágenes como [imgur](https://imgur.com/) por ejemplo. Puedes probar con una imagen de [pixabay](https://pixabay.com/es/) para verificar si te llega al correo o incluso con una alojada en Google Drive _aunque no estoy seguro si esta última opción funciona_

Comment: si tambien le puse una url absoluta pero solo imprime la etiqueta IMG como texto

Comment: Al poner line() estás poniendo texto plano. Laravel te permite utilizar un Blade template utilizando view(). Te recomiendo investigar sobre ello.

Answer (score 0):

Espero esto pueda ayudar a futuras consultas, debes embeber la imagen de la siguiente forma:

```
<img src="{{ $message->embed(public_path() . '/images/logo.png') }}" alt="" width="400" style="height:auto;display:block; padding-bottom: 20px;" />
```